# Could there be an "I don't know what forum to post this in" meta-site (kind of)?

Tags: feature-request, migration, site-recommendation

Existing SE sites have a feature that suggests what tags may be appropriate based, perhaps, on comparing keywords with existing tags.

I just had the thought, having had a few times where I wanted to ask SE a question but wasn't sure where to put it, whether it would be possible to make a meta-site where you start typing in your question and, instead of SE suggesting tags, have it suggest links to individual SE sites.

Possibly this could have a default option, if the OP does not select any of the suggested sites, being posted for the interim to an interim.stackexhange.com site, where every post is flagged for moderator attention for migration to an appropriate site with the moderator adding a comment of "I moved your question to _________ because it fits the site for this reason: __________"

Would that kind of thing be possible and/or desirable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something like that were to exist, there's at least a few logistical problems that it'd have to tackle:

1. What happens to questions that don't fit in any site?
2. What happens to questions that used to not fit in any site, but a new site gets created where this would fit?
3. What happens to questions where the topic itself is fine, but the question would get closed for other reasons if it got migrated?

Finally, even if you ironed those out, *there's no way a site like that can scale*. As an example, I counted 17 moderators listed for Stack Overflow (according to [here](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators)). If your proposed site had that many moderators and say, 5000 users, that's already nearly 300 users to a moderator. Making someone have to worry about handling 300 users worth of migrations on a regular basis would be madness, and the site wouldn't even be that big.

---

Right now, I think the closest thing to what you want would be to post here asking "Where would I post questions about X?", then going to that site and formulating your question there (the usual thing about conforming to the site's quality standards applies).

Comment: I'd tentatively like to file this as "implementation issues would be intractable for now; possibly reconsider if implementation issues are no longer so decisive."

Comment: Well, the problem is that I highly doubt the scalability issue would be solved. There's just not enough people who'd want to do the migrating.

Comment: Besides, that kind of work really should be the poster's prerogative. Just like how we ask people to research before asking on SO, posters should also take the effort to find the right site for their question. If they need guidance they can get it, but the work of putting the actual question on the right site falls on the asker.

Comment: one part of the scalability issue could be addressed by letting anyone satisfying some formula of "We think you have enough Reputation on some SE site that you're probably not a tourist or a spammer" do the migration? There still might not be enough people if anyone with some Reputation passing a sanity check could migrate, but there are more people who might try to help novices out than people fully vested as moderators.

Comment: Like I said, the issue is that there's just not enough people who'd actually want to spend all their time migrating. Nor should we put ourselves in a position where we'd need that many people just doing migrations.